# Не работает отправка JSON в Worker через Transferable Objects

Tags: javascript

Использую Worker для слияния двух крупных JS-объектов, но почему-то пересылка данных туда-обратно занимает чуть ли не по 2 секунды (так, как было до внедрения воркеров). Прочитал, что можно использовать `Transferable Object`. Якобы невероятно ускоряет скорость передачи данных в Worker и обрватно.

В посте Google Developers сказано:

> This allowed the postMessage() API to accept messages that were not just strings, but complex types like File, Blob, ArrayBuffer, and JSON objects

Ну вот я и передаю JS-объект:

```
var workerData = {
    task: 'merge',
    data: {
        new: iterationData,
        original: {
            airlines: window.airlines,
            airports: window.airports,
            filters: window.filters,
            flight_info: window.flight_info,
            gates_info: window.gates_info,
            proposal_seats: window.proposal_seats,
            proposals: window.proposals,
            filteredProposals: window.filteredProposals,
            rules: window.rules
        }
    }
}

merge_worker.postMessage(workerData, [workerData])
```

И лювлю в консоли предупреждение:

> Value at index 0 does not have a transferable type

Почему мой код не работает?

Comment: попробуйте положить вместо ваших значений в этот объект обычные строки, скорее всего, объекты на которые ссылаются поля Вашего объекта, содержат нечто, что не сериализуется, вроде объекта window

Comment: @StrangerintheQ то же самое предупреждение

Answer (score 0):

Как написано в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage), `Transferable Object` должен быть следующих типов `ArrayBuffer`, `MessagePort` или `ImageBitmap`.

> Переданные (transferable) объекты могут быть экземплярами классов
>   ArrayBuffer, MessagePort или ImageBitmap. null не является допустимым
>   значением для передачи прав.

Соответственно, вы не можете передать туда просто JS-объект.

Возможно, можно попробовать сериализовать ваш объект в `ArrayBuffer`, но не думаю, что это будет быстрее, чем слияние JS-объект.